# Having issues making content responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm in the process of converting my layout to a responsive design. I've looked at some tutorials and made some adjustments. However, when I load the page on a cell phone, iPad, or even make my window smaller, the content runs on top of each other. I was under the impression that using % instead of pixels would fix this. Am I wrong? The link is below.

http://tinyurl.com/ab2fmwv

```
article {
width: 80%;
min-height: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: solid;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
clear: both;
}
#two_column_left {
width: 74%;
float: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#two_column_right {
width: 25%;
float: right;
}
.three-col-row {
width: 100%;
float: left;
padding-top: 2%;

}

.col-1 {
width: 26%;
float: left;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.col-2 {
width: 26%;
float: left;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-bottom: 2%;

}
.col-3 {
width: 26%;
float: left;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-bottom: 2%;

}
.pic-3-col {
width: 175px;
height: 100px;
}
p.title-3-col {
color: #222020;
font-size: 1.3em;
clear: both;
}
p.description-3-col {
width: 190px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the columns size perfectly, it's contents do not. for example

```
.pic-3-col {
width: 175px;
height: 100px;
}
```

if you want a responsive fluid layout, there should not be values like this in the CSS.

Comment: So are you saying I should only use percentages right? OR perhaps in this case width: 100%; height: auto?

Comment: Yes, only percentages for width. Height doesn't matter so much, you can just let the boxes autosize themselves. You can use px for margins and padding but only if you nest the elements inside % width divs and not declare a width on the element with px/em margin/padding, since it would become 100% + 12px for example.

Answer (score 0):

you are using width in pixels for following classes

p.description-2-col     style.css line no 439       solu.   add it 'max-width 100%'

p.description-3-col    style.css line no 406        solu.   add it 'max-width 100%'

```
.pic-3-col     style.css line no 197    solu.   add it 'max-width 100%'  </br>
```

wrap images of same columns in .pic-3-col as the first column  is done

and also according to resolution keep chanding their wirdth in percentage using media queries